# Vertex AI Jupyter notebook keep setting up proxy for Jupyter Lab

Tags: google-cloud-vertex-ai

When I clicked the Vertex AI and try to access the User-managed notebooks, it keep setting up the proxy for JupyterLab and not allowing me to delete, reset or stop the notebook for at least 4 hours.
[image]

I have looked up the trouble shooting doc but didn't a solution for it.

Answer (score 0):

your instances of notebook have a pubblic ip ?
If you use a private network rember of enable on subnet used Private Google Access to ON and Private Services